# Why is pdf not displaying?

Tags: flutter

This is my code to show pdf when clicked the button but for some reason, pdf is not displaying. I don't know what to do.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:pdf_flutter/pdf_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Network PDF Viewer"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              PDF.network(
                'https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/en/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-en.pdf',
                height: 300,
                width: 200,
                placeHolder: Image.asset("assets/images/pdf.png",
                    height: 200, width: 100),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 30,
              width: 100,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Open PDF',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I want my users to access the pdf by clicking on the button but the pdf is not displaying no matter how many times I click the button.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use PDF.network as on Pressed method, instead, do it like this

```
bool openedPDF = false;
Center(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState((){openedPDF = true;});
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 30,
          width: 100,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Open PDF',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));

Visibility(
visible : openedPDF,
child:PDF.network(
            'https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/en/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-en.pdf',
            height: 300,
            width: 200,
            placeHolder: Image.asset("assets/images/pdf.png",
                height: 200, width: 100),
          );
```

Comment: still not working, still cant see the pdf

Comment: I have used the pdf in my recent app let me check the code again until do one thing, remove the button (comment) and see if actually the pdf loads or not

Comment: did you find the solution brother??

Answer (score 1):

Try this package
[flutter_cached_pdfview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cached_pdfview)

```
PDF().cachedFromUrl(widget.url,
        placeholder: (progress) => Center(
              child: Text("Loading - $progress %"),
            ),
        errorWidget: (error) => Center(
              child: Text("An error occured while opening bill PDF"),
            )),
```

upvote if you find useful